# Converting list of base 3 digits to corresponding numerical value in Haskell

Tags: haskell, recursion

Below I have defined a function that converts a list of base-3 digits to the corresponding numerical value. For example:

```
f "201" = (2 * 3^2) + (0 * 3^1) + (1 * 3^0) = 19
f "12" = 5
f "1202" = 47
f "120221" = 430
```

Here is a definition using comprehension:

```
f :: String -> Int
f str = sum (listToFinal (stringToTuples str))
```

Helper functions:

-- 1) converts "201" to "102"

```
reverse "str"
```

-- 2) converts "102" to 102

```
stringToInt :: String -> Int
stringToInt str = read str :: Int
```

-- 3) converts 102 to ['1','0','2']

```
intToList :: Int -> [Int]
intToList 0 = []
intToList x = intToList (x `div` 10) ++ [x `mod` 10]
```

-- 4) converts "201" to [(1,0),(0,1),(2,2)] using reverse, stringToInt, intToList

```
stringToTuples :: String -> [(Int,Int)]
stringToTuples str = zip (intToList (stringToInt (reverse str))) [0..]
```

-- 5) converts [(1,0),(0,1),(2,2)] to [1*3^0, 0*3^1, 2*3^2]

```
listToFinal :: [(Int,Int)] -> [Int]
listToFinal list = [ x * (3^y) | (x,y) <- list ]
```

Now I'd like to do it with recursion only (well, using basic & library functions too, of course).

An idea: I was thinking of taking the head of each element in the list and simply multiplying it with 3^(length of string - 1). The only problem is, with each recursive call the power of three would have to decrease by 1, e.g. given:

```
recursive_version "201" = (2 * 3^2) + (0 * 3^1) + (1 * 3^0)
```

**How to implement this?**

Comment: Take a number, then append a digit on the *right*. What happebs with the number can be described by a simple formula that does not involve powers or lenghth of anything. Contrast to adding digits on the left.

Comment: Perhaps this will give you some hints `> foldl (\x y -> 3*x+y) 0 [1,2,2]`

Comment: Sorry I'm not getting it.. Could you elaborate slightly more please?

Comment: karakfa, thanks, that's a worthwhile insight! But what I'm trying to understand is how to define this recursively..

Comment: If you are replying to someone, mention them like this @Leon, this way they will be notified.

Comment: @karakfa that's really cool - I like how it seems to disguise the more common enumeration of powers for each digit.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a much simpler approach; note that, through the use of `foldl`, it's only "implicitly" recursive, though. For information, `digitToInt` is exported by `Data.Char`.

```
import Data.Char
import Data.List ( foldl' )

--- horner x xs : the value of polynomial 'xs' at point 'x'
horner :: Int -> [Int] -> Int
horner x = foldl' (\c1 c0 -> c1 * x + c0) 0

-- f s : the integer whose representation in base 3 is string 's'
f :: String -> Int
f = horner 3 . map digitToInt
```

Answer (score 0):

When you define it recursively, the natural way to decrement the length is trimming the array from the head.  For example:

```
base3 x = base3' x 0 where
  base3' (d:ds) v = base3' ds $ v + d * 3 ^ length ds
  base3' [] v = v
```